# In Alien: Isolation, can save-reload help with achievements?

Tags: achievements, alien-isolation

There are five achievements in Alien: Isolation relating to not doing certain things:

> **Mercy or Prudence?**
> Completed the game without killing any humans
>
> **Just out of Reach**
> Contacted your team and escaped Comms without being attacked by an android
>
> **Hide. Run. Survive.**
> Completed "The Quarantine" without being killed by the Alien
>
> **One Shot**
> Completed the game without dying

Secret:

> **Mind Your Step**
>  Navigated Reactor Maintenance without dying

For any of these can you still get them if you:

- Quit and reload before the animation completes
- Reload a checkpoint
- Reload the previous save
- Reload the mission save
- Restart from the mission?

Or is the only option to restart the entire game?

Comment: I can confirm that *Just out of Reach* and *Hide. Run. Survive.* can be attained by quickly loading the last checkpoint before the working joe or Alien touches you. I can also confirm that if the Alien does kill you the last save is updated but the level save doesn't appear to be, so reloading the mission save should work.

Comment: I can also confirm _Mind Your Step_ is attainable by loading the previous save after you die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After completing the game I can confirm that the following works for all of the above except *Mercy or Prudence?*

- If you're quick you can hit pause and reload before you die. You'll see a tape icon in the top right if you're too late.
- Certain late game enemies (from the reactor maintenance on) will not let you pause once the death animation starts, so be very careful around them.
- If you're not quick enough then the current save is compromised, however the following works:
- Load the current save
- Then pause and select the previous save

Note that if you get killed before you save again you'll have to go back to the mission save.

For  *Mercy or Prudence?* it appears that you have to load the mission save at least, but I can't confirm that as I didn't kill anyone.

Answer (score 0):

For "Just out of Reach" when android attacks you just load last (current) checkpoint. Works for me. Been attacked once by that laying android , load current and after finishing I get the achievement.